# Get-ADComputer and MemberOf

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I am very new to Powershell and am having an issue when using the `Get-ADUser` and `GetADComputer` cmdlets.

I am trying to use the `Get-ADComputer` and `Get-ADUser` to retrieve the `memberOf` from Active-Directory of all the users and computers. It only appears to be retrieving information from users and computers that are in 2 or more groups. Any users/computers that are only in 1 group display nothing.

For example: If UserA is in group Administrators I get no output when I use MemberOf. But if User2 is in both Administrators and Domains Administrators I get some output. However it will only output one of those groups.

Get-ADGroup does the same thing.

Is this normal? I can't imagine it is.

Here is my code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,MemberOf | Sort-Object -Property Name
```

Thanks

Comment: Check out this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009593/list-group-memberships-for-ad-users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trouble comes from the fact that the primary group is not part of the `memberOf` attribute.

So try this :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,MemberOf,PrimaryGroup | Sort-Object -Property Name
```

You'll find a deeper explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776289/608772).